# Can't enter more than 9 numbers or remove all entered numbers in a textbox

Tags: vb.net

So i'm making a program for school that's supposed to convert temperatures from Celsius to farenheit and vice-versa. The program works fine but when i try to enter more than 9 numbers in the textbox it crashes. The same problem occurs when i try to backspace and delete numbers previously entered. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
Private Sub txtEntré_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtEntré.KeyPress
    'Laisse seulement tapper des chiffres dans la boîte de texte
    If cbEntré.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
        txtEntré.ReadOnly = True
    Else
        txtEntré.ReadOnly = False

    End If
    If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") _
       AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbEntré.SelectedIndexChanged
    If cbEntré.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        cbSortie.SelectedIndex = 0
    ElseIf cbEntré.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        cbSortie.SelectedIndex = 1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtEntré_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtEntré.TextChanged

    Dim Entré As Integer
    Convert.ToInt64(txtEntré.Text)

    If cbEntré.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        txtSortie.Text = (Entré * 9 / 5) + 32
    ElseIf cbEntré.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        txtSortie.Text = (Entré - 32) * 5 / 9
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Well if you delete all of the text then this line `Convert.ToInt64(textEntre.Text)` is going to throw a `FormatException` so you should check for empty string before performing that conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You code seem to be missing something and you haven't told us the error. I'll assume that you put the data from the textbox into Entré. Since Entré is an [integer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32?view=netframework-4.7.2), it's range of value is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. Any number beyond that range will fail. That must be why you can't go beyond 9 character (well.. 1 as the first character should work).

If you change your variable to an [Int64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int64?view=netframework-4.7.2), then the range is -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 which is much bigger.

Comment: Good catch here - I hadn't seen the type mismatch between the declared variable as `Integer` and the `Convert.ToInt64`.  Between the empty string case and this, I bet that covers the crashing.

Comment: Yes, but who deals with temperature values over 2 billion? He should limit the textbox to something more reasonable, or use a parse function that fails more gracefully, or both.

Comment: Is there any way i can get it do display a message like "please do not enter more than 8 characters" instead of it just crashing the application? Also do you know why it crashes when i delete all the numbers that were entered int the text box

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking specifically at the method below:

```
Private Sub txtEntré_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtEntré.TextChanged

    Dim Entré As Integer
    Convert.ToInt64(txtEntré.Text)

    If cbEntré.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        txtSortie.Text = (Entré * 9 / 5) + 32
    ElseIf cbEntré.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        txtSortie.Text = (Entré - 32) * 5 / 9
    End If

End Sub
```

First of all, this line:

```
Dim Entré As Integer
```

This is a [**32-bit** value.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/integer-data-type)

But now the next line is trying to create a **64-bit** value:

```
Convert.ToInt64(txtEntré.Text)
```

Additionally, the result is not assigned anywhere, leaving `Entré` **unchanged** from the default value of `0`.

Either change `Entré` to use a `Long` type, or change this code to use `Convert.ToInt32()` (or, even better, `Integer.TryParse()`).

Given you're dealing with temperature values, I recommend the latter option. I doubt you need to worry about temperatures greater than the 2+ billion degrees you can represent with a basic integer. Not even the core of the Sun gets that hot. You can set the `MaxLength` property of the TextBox to `8` to keep safe.

Either way, don't forget to the assign the result to your variable:

```
Private Sub txtEntré_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtEntré.TextChanged    
    Dim Entré As Integer 
    If Not Integer.TryParse(txtEntré.Text, Entré) Then Exit Sub

    If cbEntré.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        txtSortie.Text = ((Entré * 9 / 5) + 32).ToString()
    ElseIf cbEntré.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        txtSortie.Text = ((Entré - 32) * 5 / 9).ToString()
    End If
End Sub
```

You should also turn on Option Strict.

Comment: Which I could upvote twice for the `Option Strict` comment.